# Circular Progress Timer Animation in Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation, timer

I'm trying to use the MBCircularProgress framework to create an animated circular timer. I'm not sure how to link it with time I've set (I'm using the MZTimerLabel framework). Here is what I have so far:

```
// workout time
let workoutTimeLong = 30.0

// the view of type MBCircularProgressBarView
@IBOutlet weak var progressTimer: MBCircularProgressBarView!

//the timer label
@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: MZTimerLabel!

self.progressTimer.setValue(55, animateWithDuration: 1)
```

I did look at the given methods but this is my first project in Swift so I'm lost as to how to connect it via code. The above code gives me a "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" error. Thanks.

Comment: I don't even know what MBCircularProgress is.  Is it edible?

Comment: I mentioned in my OP that it's a framework.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you have this line at the top of your file.

```
import MBCircularProgressBar
```

I don't fully understand what you mean by linking it with the time you have set but it might look something like this.

```
progressBar.setValue(CGFloat(workoutTimeLong), animateWithDuration: 1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful but I'm getting the Thread 1: EXC_BAD_EXECUTION error which i why I was doubtful about my implementation. Also the view isn't showing up either. Is there an extra step that I'm missing out on?